# Which programming languages are available for developing native apps in tizen OS?

Tags: tizen, tizen-native-app

Which programming languages are available for developing native apps in tizen OS?

Comment: from Wikipedia : Available programming languages(s) : HTML5, C, C++. Tizen provides application development tools based on the JavaScript libraries jQuery and jQuery Mobile. Since version 2.0, a native application framework is also available, based on Open Services Platform from the Bada platform.
The software development kit (SDK) allows developers to use HTML5 and related web technologies to write applications that run on supported devices.

Comment: Did you look into the Tizen SDK?

Comment: There is also port of Qt for Tizen (C++ framework)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

C++ and HTML5.  We have a guide on porting apps over from HTML5: http://tools.appbackr.com/porting-html5-apps-tizen-guide/

The important steps to add are

1. hardware button functionality is required
2. the screen resolution

Comment: Thanks to the viewport the screen resolution is not so important - application may be scaled. 
Hardware button can be served via JavaScript. Please take a look at sample apps in the SDK.

Answer (score 8):

Apart from C++ and HTML 5 it also supports C at system level.

Answer (score 1):

Native app development in Tizen can also be done using EFL libraries and c programming.
You will have to write your graphics files or lets say screen using edc (Edje Data Collection a componant of EFL), and then you will map these edc files with your c programs for UI callbacks.

for edc reference
http://docs.enlightenment.org/auto/edje/edcref.html

Answer (score 1):

Native Application written in- 
1. Application written in Core APIs
    UI Application - Applications with UI 
     - Developed using EFL + Core APIs
2. Service Application - Applications without UI
     - Developed using Core APIs
Both are written with C++.

Answer (score 1):

Along with C/C++ , HTML/JS/CSS

**.NET**

Check this out...

https://developer.tizen.org/development/preview